# Laravel Storage Carbon Exception

Tags: php, laravel, upload, storage

I'm trying to upload a file and I have an error from Carbon Exception.
The code :

```
$filename = Str::uuid().'.'.request()->file('identity')->extension();
            $path = request()->file('identity')->storeAs('deads/identities/'.$dead->id, $filename);
            $dead->identity_path = $path;
            $dead->save();
```

and the Carbon Exception error :

> Carbon\Exceptions\InvalidFormatException
> Could not parse 'deads/identities/1/1dada0cc-adca-420f-9b21-3e8c106a62b8.png': DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (deads/identities/1/1dada0cc-adca-420f-9b21-3e8c106a62b8.png) at position 0 (d): The timezone could not be found in the database

The file is stored in the folder, so I don't understand what I'm doing wrong with this code ?

Comment: What is the type of identity_path attribute in your database? It seems you are trying to convert the file path to a datetime, and that's of course causing a Carbon error.

Comment: On `app.php` add your timezone as like `'timezone' => 'UTC'`

Comment: @Urudin The type of identity_path is varchar(191) utf8mb4 utf8m4_unicode_ci nullable.

Comment: @sta I tryed to change the timezone in the config/app.php but same error.

Comment: But in your code, you are not using Carbon

Comment: @sta Nope I'm not using Carbon.

Comment: On your `Str` model, there are 2 field as default, `created_at` and `updated_at` lsravel uses the Carbon by default. may be you getting this error from there. Some how Carbon accept `deads/identities/1/1dada0cc-adca-420f-9b21-3e8c106a62b8.png` as a time and want to parse it. That's why you getting this error. Do you post the `Str` model on your question?

Comment: @sta I don't have a Str model in the application, this is the strings helper you can see here in the Laravel doc https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-str-uuid. I tryed with a single string of characters and the same error appears.

Comment: And if I try just like that : $path = $request->file('identity')->store('deads/identities/'.$dead->id);
                $dead->identity_path = $path;  I've the same error to.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if ($request->hasFile('identity')) {
  $img_ext = $request->identity->extension();
  $filename = time().'.'.$img_ext;
  $request->identity->move(public_path('upload/'), $filename);//create upload folder in 
  public
  //save upload image to database
  $variable->image = $filename;  
}
$variable->save();
```

Comment: I'm constrained to use Storage file disk system on this project. I can't store directly in the public folder wtih the move() method :(

Comment: `$filename = Str::uuid().'.'.request()->file('identity')->extension();`
`$path = request()->file('identity')->storeAs('deads/identities/'.$dead->id, $filename);`
`$dead->identity_path = $filename;`
`$dead->save();`

Comment: You should  change `$dead->identity_path = $filename;` instead of  `$dead->identity_path = $path;`

Answer (score 0):

My mistakes! I have set the identity_path field to

```
protected $dates = ['identity_path'];
```

in the model.

Of course that's causing a Carbon error...